# Not full width css horizontal menu

Tags: css, menu

Relatively new to CSS, so please bear with my inexperience. I'm trying to create a menu, and after much searching and comparison and reading and copying, I've mostly come up with the format I want. The problem is that I want my menu to be the width of its content, not full width, and the code below (adapted from various examples) yields a full width menu. I've played around with things, but can't seem to identify what makes it full width or not -- it may be that what I want requires a more substantial rewrite.

In case it helps, what I want is a horizontal menu with an outer rectangular border, with width determined by its contents, not automatically full width (or even, not automatically a specified width).

This is my first time posting a question here, so thanks in advance for your help and patience!

```
<style type="text/css">

*/#menu ul,#menu li,#menu a{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-family: Arial}

#menu{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-radius:5px}

#menu ul{
    background:#ffffff;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border-radius:5px}

#menu ul:before{
    content:'';
    display:block}

#menu ul:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both}

#menu li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border:0px}

#menu li a{
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px 10px 5px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000000;
    border:0px;
    font-size:15px}

</style>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link4</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Set #menu { display: inline-block; } now it will gets width according to its content .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul` are **block level** elements are so are 100% wide by default.

Make the `ul` display as `inline-block` and it will collapse to the width of it's contents.

Add `text-align` to the parent as required. Here I used `center`.

```css
#menu ul,
#menu li,
#menu a {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}
#menu {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px
}
#menu ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block
}
#menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both
}
#menu li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border: 0px
}
#menu li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 15px
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link2</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link3</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link4</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```